# Connecting to TFS Git repository when already connected

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2015

I connected to our team project, but setting up the folder and Git repository outside of Visual Studio. I noticed I was not getting many of the features of TFS and Git in Visual Studio 2015, so I connected to our Git Server, and now see items like 'Pull Requests'. However, when I go into the 'Pull Requests' areas, I get the message:

> You are not connected to a remote repository.

Also, even tho the TFS server has pull requests, there are none listed here.

I have been able to commit, push, and pull code from Visual Studio, so I know I am connected. Any ideas why I get this message or how to get rid of it?

Comment: You mentioned Git server and TFS server, are you using your own Git server or the TFS hosted Git repository?

Comment: TFS hosted GIT. I figured it out. I had cloned the repository in Bash, then opened the solution in VS. If I cloned the repository in VS, everything works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

The **pull request** in TFS will not list on your GIT server. It's better to clone the repository in the VS team project onto your dev machine. Otherwise, there are just local repositories to TFS. After that you can manage all pull requests such as *requested by me*, *assigned to me*, *assigned to team* in **web portal of TFS**.

More detail info about how to create, manage , complete the pull request in TFS, please refer the official documentation: [Use Git pull requests to review code](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/pull-requests)

[image]

Moreover, here is a great [post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2013/01/30/getting-started-with-git-in-visual-studio-and-team-foundation-service/) will help you quickly getting started with Git in Visual Studio and Team Foundation Server.